# When to call function JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a button on the form. When I press that button I would like to call the functions. As it is now I will need to click the button twice since information is not updated after the button click.

```
<f:metadata>      
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{playerAverageChartBeanTotal.CreateChart()}"/>
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{playerAverageChartBean.CreateChart()}"/>
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{serviceHCP.getClubs(player)}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply attach an action listener to that button instead?

Comment: Can i do that for all three functions? Or you mean that I should call one function and then extract the context?

Comment: Can't you just call all of these three functions from an action listener of `<h:commandButton>` in your JSF managed bean?

Comment: only thought it was one function that could be called. Will need to check that out

Comment: We can inject the desired beans in our target bean using the `@ManagedProperty` annotation something like `@ManagedProperty(value="#{yourBean}"); private YourBean yourBean; //Getter and setter` and invoke any methods we like of this bean from the target bean provided that the scope the injected beans must be equal or higher than the target bean (`YourBean` in this case). If you need specific properties to be injected into the target bean, you can do the same with the same annotation, `@ManagedProperty(value="#{yourProperty}") private YourProperty yourProperty; //Getter and setter`.